# Disabling memory dump in a Windows 8.1 phone application

Tags: c#, security, debugging, windows-phone-8.1, dump

I have developed a mobile application in .NET C# for my WP8.1 phone.

If I turn on "Settings/feedback/Save info" option in the phone settings, if the application happens to crash, a snapshot of the memory will be written to "\MyPhone\Phone\Documents\Debug\fooBar.dmp" on the phone. 
[image: Debug info setting]

1. Let's assume the crash is inevitable, for staying on point.
2. Let's also assume that the binary is only on the phone, and nobody can
   access it.

By connecting the phone to my PC via USB, I can access these memory dumps, which is a risk from a security perspective, because you could read sensitive information from these dumps (source code, strings, user credentials).

This application won't be uploaded to the Application store, and is only used internally with a few selected people.

**So, I need a way to disable these memory dumps FROM my application, even if it's enabled in OS settings. Like can I "flag" my app, or use some code to prevent dumps being written to the phone where anybody can access it?**

Comment: _"you could read sensitive information from these dumps"_ - people interested in that can run your app in a sandbox / VM and inspect the memory all they like.

Comment: You can't try to catch the possible exceptions and close the app gracefully? Seems like this is a app stability issue, not a WP8 OS issue...